# change specific values of array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

```
<?php
$x=6;
$y=9;
$time = array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);

for ($i=$x;$i<=count($y);$i++)
{
   If($x!=$y)
{

   $time[$i]=1;
}

}

?>
```

Depending on the value of x and y,the values in array should change.
In this example... array[5] until array[8] should be value 1.
The value of x and y will not same.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Using the above code,I could not get the results.is the code right.

Comment: `$i<=count($y)`.... $y is simply an integer, why count it? (especially as the count is 1, because it's only 1 integer)

Comment: your question is not clear.What is your desired output?

Comment: And why `If($x!=$y)`? Why not simply set `$y` to the correct value in the first place, or even just use `<` rather than `<=` in your `for()` loop

Comment: `for ($i=$x;$i<$y;$i++)
{
   $time[$i]=1;
}
`

Answer (score 1):

Not a very good question, but I'm a little bored.  So for fun:

```
array_splice($time, $x-1, $y-$x-1, array_fill(0, $y-$x+1, 1));
```

Not exactly sure of the logic using 6 and 9 and array[5] until array[8] is, but adjust the numbers to fit the range.